# Change data type in a SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a view called `dbo.NpsResultsView`.

The code for this view is:

```
SELECT        
    dbo.CRMDeals.dealid,
    dbo.CRMDeals.contact,
    dbo.CRMContacts.title,
    dbo.CRMContacts.firstname,
    dbo.CRMContacts.lastname, 
    dbo.CRMContacts.dealCustomFieldId,
    dbo.CRMCustomFieldsData.fieldValue,
    dbo.CRMCustomFieldsData.updatedTimestamp, 
    dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Groups AS Expr1, 
    dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Client,
    dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Email,
    dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.ClientManager
FROM
    dbo.CRMDeals
INNER JOIN    
    dbo.CRMContacts ON dbo.CRMContacts.contactid = dbo.CRMDeals.contact 
INNER JOIN    
    dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData ON dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData.dealId = dbo.CRMDeals.dealid 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset ON dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Email = dbo.CRMContacts.email
WHERE        
    (dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData.dealCustomFieldId = '15')
```

In that view, I have a column called `fieldValue` which is returned as `VarChar`, and this needs to be `int` as it's a score out of 10.

Note: using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you cannot use this command to change the definition for a view. To change the view definition, you must drop the view and then recreate it.

```
CREATE VIEW AView
AS
SELECT CAST(title AS char(50))
FROM titles
```

You can use cast and covert function to change a datatype

Answer (score 3):

Use `CAST(fieldValue AS INT)` in your view definition - or if you want to avoid an exception when a value in `fieldValue` isn't really an `INT`, maybe use `TRY_CAST(fieldValue AS INT)`. Then any "improper" value will be replaced by `NULL` instead of throwing an exception.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.NpsResultsView
AS
    SELECT        
        dbo.CRMDeals.dealid,
        dbo.CRMDeals.contact,
        dbo.CRMContacts.title,
        dbo.CRMContacts.firstname,
        dbo.CRMContacts.lastname, 
        dbo.CRMContacts.dealCustomFieldId,
        TRY_CAST(dbo.CRMCustomFieldsData.fieldValue AS INT) AS 'fieldValueInt',
        dbo.CRMCustomFieldsData.updatedTimestamp, 
        dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Groups AS Expr1, 
        dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Client,
        dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Email,
        dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.ClientManager
    FROM
        dbo.CRMDeals
    INNER JOIN    
        dbo.CRMContacts ON dbo.CRMContacts.contactid = dbo.CRMDeals.contact 
    INNER JOIN    
        dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData ON dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData.dealId = dbo.CRMDeals.dealid 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset ON dbo.ClientsMigrationDataset.Email = dbo.CRMContacts.email
    WHERE         
        (dbo.CRMDealCustomFieldsData.dealCustomFieldId = '15')
```